# ChromeDriver showing Lost UI Shared Context

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver

I have a Windows 10 laptop running a Windows 7 Virtual Machine. Inside the Virtual Machine, when i start the WebDriver, it gives the error *gpu_process_transport_factory.cc<1009> Lost UI shared context* when it is started:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver() //This causes the 1009 Error
```

[image: ERROR]

Also then varies for *Failed to query stereo recording* and *Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer* **and** *command_buffer_proxy_impll.cc<115> Shared memory handle is not valid*.

This has been **working for months** and **no changes were made** (this WebDriver is the sole purpose of the Virtual Machine), the laptop running it is running fine (ie. no GPU problems). The WebDriver still navigates through pages, but giving further errors and 10x slower.

**EDIT**: Updated to ChromeDriver to 2.35 and still the same behavior.

Comment: What version of Chrome is your machine using? I just recently started having this issue and noticed the machines that get the error are on version 65 while the machines that work are on version 64.

Comment: Would this affect the ability to perform mouse-related controls?  ie - mouseButtonDown, moveTo, etc ?

Answer (score 8):

*Headless Chrome* was shipped in **Chrome 59** by *Google Team* which introduced a way to run the *Chrome Browser* in a *Headless Environment*.

A note was added as :

```
Headless mode has been available on Mac and Linux since Chrome 59. Windows support came in Chrome 60.
```

The article [**`Getting Started with Headless Chrome`**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) mentioned that :

```
--disable-gpu \                # Temporarily needed if running on Windows.
```

A note was added as :

> Right now, you'll also want to include the `--disable-gpu` flag if you're running on Windows.

As per the discussion [**`Headless: make --disable-gpu flag unnecessary`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737678) it was clear that :

> The `--disable-gpu` flag is no longer necessary on *Linux* or *Mac OSX*. It will also become unnecessary on Windows as soon as the bug [**`SwiftShader fails an assert on Windows in headless mode`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=729961) is fixed.

### What happened under the hood?

As per the discussion [**`headless: Switch from osmesa to SwiftShader`**](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/522068) as Google/Chromium team decided to ship **SwiftShader** with **Chrome**, the team thought to start using it to render *GL content* in *Headless Mode*. This required a couple of changes as follows :

- Skip GPU data collection in *Headless Mode* since **SwiftShader** isn't considered a software implementation by that code which lead to a failure when we tried to retrieve information from the **Window System**.
- Only skip *GL initialization* in *InitializeStaticEGLInternal* if we intend to use **osmesa**. **SwiftShader** requires initialization like the other non-software implementations.
- **SwiftShader** is currently not supported on *Mac OSX*, so the team decided to continue to use the *physical GPU* in *Headless Mode* on that platform (unlike on other platforms where everything is software rendered).
- So, to disable **WebGL** support in *Headless Mode* they decided to use **--disable-gpu** and **--disable-software-rasterizer**

The idea to [**`Support WebGL in headless`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617551) is still under discussion but [**`SwiftShader fails an assert on Windows in headless mode`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=729961) with an error  as :

```
[0117/125830.649194:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1043)] Lost UI shared context.
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:37429/devtools/browser/1f0b2bf7-dfdd-44ac-9da7-f2659d352f0d
```

### Conclusion

This error doesn't impact your `@Test` and you can ignore the error for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an issue with the latest version of Chrome (65.0.3325.146). By rolling back to an earlier version of Chrome (64.0.3282.186) the issue disappeared for me.

Will investigate further and update here if I find any more info but as a temporary workaround you can uninstall chrome and install version 64.0.3282.186.

Comment: @rebecca sparks Just uninstall Chrome and install an older version. You can download older versions of chrome here: https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

Answer (score 3):

'Lost UI Shared Context' was mistaken for an error while it's actually a logging output.

This has been fixed since Chrome 72.0. no extraneous arguments needed.