# DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/d6cd5add-200d-4bf7-b1ec-12f743092efc and subsequent Timeout

Tags: selenium, spring-boot, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

I try to run springboot application which is using selenium on heroku.
Locally everything works fine, but when my application

```
2018-09-09T11:42:25.404810+00:00 app[web.1]: [0909/114225.404404:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.
2018-09-09T11:42:25.405652+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-09T11:42:25.405742+00:00 app[web.1]: DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/d6cd5add-200d-4bf7-b1ec-12f743092efc
```

and after that selenium throws an error:`Timed out waiting for driver server to start.`

On heroku I'm using https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver and https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Let us look at the trace logs you have shared:

- `[0909/114225.404404:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.`

  - This error doesn't impact your `@Test` and you can ignore the error for the time being.
  - You can find a detailed discussion in [ChromeDriver showing Lost UI Shared Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094399/chromedriver-showing-lost-ui-shared-context)
- `DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/d6cd5add-200d-4bf7-b1ec-12f743092efc`

  - This error even doesn't impact your `@Test` and you can ignore the error for the time being.
  - You can find a detailed discussion in [DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57671/devtools/browser/8a586f7c-5f2c-4d10-8174-7a7bf50e49b5 with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245604/devtools-listening-on-ws-127-0-0-157671-devtools-browser-8a586f7c-5f2c-4d10-8)
- You main issue is with `Timed out waiting for driver server to start.` and clearly indicates that your *WebDriver* / *Server* process havn't spanned and have timed out.

### Solution

You need to cross check the *WebDriver* / *Web Browser* initiation/initialzation part of your code to solve this error.