# DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57671/devtools/browser/8a586f7c-5f2c-4d10-8174-7a7bf50e49b5 with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am using python + selenium for web browser automation and getting this error.

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57671/devtools/browser/8a586f7c-5f2c-4d10-8174-7a7bf50e49b5
[5096:1196:0909/183254.362:ERROR:mf_helpers.cc(14)] Error in dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc on line 517
```

The problem arises when the program reaches this part of code:-

```
def send_comments(driver):
    add_comments = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('add') 
    comments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//form[@class='addCommentexpand']//textarea[contains(@placeholder,'Add a comment')]") 
    submit_comments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[text()='Comment']")  
    i = 0
    for add, comment, submit in zip(add_comments, comments, submit_comments):
        print("comment begins")
        add.click()
        print("+add comment clicked")
        comment.click()
        print("comment textbox clicked")
        comment.send_comments("Amazing Art")
        print("text typed")
        submit.click()
        print("comment submited")
        i += 1
        if i > 5:
            driver.close()

send_comments(driver)
```

Its also not logging in console. Can anyone tell whats the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/

@AndreaCardaci in the documentation [**Load a URL in a separate context**](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/wiki/Load-a-URL-in-a-separate-context-(headless-mode-only)) mentions that when using *Google Chrome in Headless Mode*:

> The usual example code is run in a new disposable tab in a separated context (think of it as incognito profiles) each time.

As inorder to fetch the browser version since Chrome 62 the browser target URL is generated at runtime and can be obtained via the **`/json/version`** endpoint and fallback to **`/devtools/browser`** if not present.

Here is the relevant code:

```
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');

async function doInNewContext(action) {
    // fetch the browser version (since Chrome 62 the browser target URL is
    // generated at runtime and can be obtained via the '/json/version'
    // endpoint, fallback to '/devtools/browser' if not present)
    const {webSocketDebuggerUrl} = await CDP.Version();
    // connect to the DevTools special target
    const browser = await CDP({
        target: webSocketDebuggerUrl || 'ws://localhost:9222/devtools/browser'
    });
    // create a new context
    const {Target} = browser;
    const {browserContextId} = await Target.createBrowserContext();
    const {targetId} = await Target.createTarget({
        url: 'about:blank',
        browserContextId
    });
    // connct to the new context
    const client = await CDP({target: targetId});
    // perform user actions on it
    try {
        await action(client);
    } finally {
        // cleanup
        await Target.closeTarget({targetId});
        await browser.close();
    }
}

// this basically is the usual example
async function example(client) {
    // extract domains
    const {Network, Page} = client;
    // setup handlers
    Network.requestWillBeSent((params) => {
        console.log(params.request.url);
    });
    // enable events then start!
    await Promise.all([Network.enable(), Page.enable()]);
    await Page.navigate({url: 'https://github.com'});
    await Page.loadEventFired();
}

doInNewContext(example);
```

Moreover as per [Obtain the browser target URL (ws://localhost:9222/devtools/browser/...) programmatically](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=756425) the endpoint is available over `http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version` in a **`webSocketDebuggerUrl`** field. So alternatively, if you are starting chrome with the option `--remote-debugging-port=0`, both **port** and **endpoint** are written to the **DevToolsAcivePort** file in browser profile folder.

### Conclusion

This error doesn't impact your `@Test` and you can ignore the error for the time being.

Comment: so i just add that code in the beginning of my program

Comment: @SultanMorbiwala Nopes, I have added the code which is being used to initialize the _new disposable tab in a separated context_ for your reference. This error basically have no impact on your tests.

Comment: @SultanMorbiwala Glad to be able to help you. Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Chanticleer in [hide chromeDriver console in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983860/hide-chromedriver-console-in-python)

In your Python folder, find and edit this file:

```
Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\services.py
```

Edit the Start() function by adding the creation flags this way: `creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW`

```
from win32process import CREATE_NO_WINDOW

def start(self):
    """
    Starts the Service.

    :Exceptions:
     - WebDriverException : Raised either when it can't start the service
       or when it can't connect to the service
    """
    try:
        cmd = [self.path]
        cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                        close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                        stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
    except TypeError:
        raise
```

It works perfectly for me using python3.7 and selenium 3.141.0

Answer (score 0):

For others who cannot modify the packages source code (because it needs to work after pip install!!), thanks to @Denis, this actually worked for me:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
```

It removed the annyoing JQMITIGATE log..

(I can't comment or anything, that's why I'm writing this answer..)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
```

Answer (score -1):

This is work:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning) 
...
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```