# python selenium Chrome driver disable devtools

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

**How to disable devtools in chrome driver?**

**python shell output**:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49881/devtools/browser/0bdaee9f-7293-479b-88dd-69e1223a92ac
```

**code**

```
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")  # fatal
    chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option( "prefs",{'profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript': 2})       
    chrome_path = 'drivers/chromedriver.exe'
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
    self.driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: Check this discussion [DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57671/devtools/browser/8a586f7c-5f2c-4d10-8174-7a7bf50e49b5 with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245604/devtools-listening-on-ws-127-0-0-157671-devtools-browser-8a586f7c-5f2c-4d10-8)