# Scrapyd won't deploy a spider-project containing selenium module to my local host

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver, scrapyd

I am trying to deploy my scrapy-spider on my local host through scrapyd, The spider script contains the selenium module to perform some web automated tasks. the problem arises when I try to deploy it.

After running the scrapyd from command line to run the local host. I type the local host address on my browser and its online and listening. Then type in the the scrapyd-deploy command on another cmd window and its gets stuck like this for hours(no error msg).

```
$ scrapyd-deploy local
Packing version 1560251984
Deploying to project "crawler" in http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
```

[stuck image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvhqS.png)

I'm using gitbash on my windows machine by the way, I've also tried using normal cmd but it still the same endless wait and delay.

On the first cmd window where i run the scrapyd command to open the local host, i get something like this.

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9137/devtools/browser/07f179fa-02ce-4b31-a5
96-9b700654f105
```

[devtools listening stuck image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77KHW.png)

To my understanding that seems to be the selenium browser in headless mode trying to initiate but it keeps waiting endlessly.

When i open my project directory, i see new folders like eggs, project-egg info and build. It seems it eggifies the project but runs through a delay when trying to deploy and run it on local host.

**this is my spider script**

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Webwait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as exco
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

C_options = Options()
C_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
C_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
C_options.add_argument("--headless")

class CloupAppSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=C_options,
                              executable_path=r"C:\.....\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/basic_login/")
    cookie = driver.get_cookies()
    driver.add_cookie(cookie[0])
    name = 'crawl'
    allowed_domains = ['scrapingclub.com']
    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/basic_login/']

    def __int__(self, name=None, passwd=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CloupAppSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.name = name

    def parse(self, response):
        pword = self.passwd
        uname = self.name
        Webwait(self.driver, 10).until(exco.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_name")))
        Webwait(self.driver, 10).until(exco.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_password")))
        CloupAppSpider.driver.find_element_by_id("id_name").send_keys(pword)
        CloupAppSpider.driver.find_element_by_id("id_password").send_keys(uname)
        CloupAppSpider.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary").click()
        Webwait(self.driver, 10).until(exco.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "col-lg-8")))
        html = CloupAppSpider.driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
        bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        text = bs_obj.find("div", {"class": "col-lg-8"}).find("p")
        obj = text.get_text()
        obj = obj + str(random.randint(0, 100))
        self.driver.close()
        yield{
            'text': obj
        }
```

**This is my scrapy.cfg content**

```
[settings]
default = crawler.settings
[deploy:local]
url = http://localhost:6800/
project = crawler
```

Can someone help explain to me where i went wrong, I am clueless as i didn't get any error code when deploying. it just keeps waiting endlessly, my guess is when it's trying to process with selenium.

Comment: If you run `http://localhost:6800` what happens?

Comment: @Umair  Initially the local host opens after the scrapyd command in cmd, but after I try to deploy it with (scrapyd-deploy local), then It doesn't open any more, the web page keeps loading endlessly also.

Comment: is your scrapyd running? or something else is running on that port?

Comment: @Umair after i type the scrapyd command on cmd, it opens the local host and runs it on the webpage. but after i try to deploy with (scrapyd-deploy) the local host web page doesn't open anymore, it keeps loading. I don't have any knowledge of something else on that port, apart from scrapyd.

Comment: is your scrapyd and the project you are working on are both on same machine? probably set `bind-address=0.0.0.0` in your `scrapyd.conf` file

Comment: okay i will try your suggestion now, thanks for the help so far. I'm also running the project and scrapyd on the same machine

Comment: @Umair I tried it and now I'm getting an error at least, in my scrapyd cmd window, DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:22265/devtools/browser/a472c99f-a0c1-47d5-b
b21-11975b70743d
[0612/155022.106:ERROR:mf_helpers.cc(14)] Error in dxva_video_decode_accelerator
_win.cc on line 511

Comment: @Umair i found a question on here similar to my error code at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245604/devtools-listening-on-ws-127-0-0-157671-devtools-browser-8a586f7c-5f2c-4d10-8#_=_) am gonna try their solution and see where it leads me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. my mistake was that, I initiated the selenium process under the main spider class, instead of under the def parse function contained in the spider class. I just re-edited the code as follows.

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Webwait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as exco
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

C_options = Options()
C_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
C_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
C_options.add_argument("--headless")

class CloupAppSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'crawl'
    allowed_domains = ['scrapingclub.com']
    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/basic_login/']

    def __int__(self, name=None, passwd=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CloupAppSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.name = name

    def parse(self, response):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=C_options,                                  
         executable_path=r"C:\......\chromedriver.exe")
        driver.get("https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/basic_login/")
        cookie = driver.get_cookies()
        driver.add_cookie(cookie[0])
        pword = self.passwd
        uname = self.name
        Webwait(self.driver, 10).until(exco.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_name")))
        Webwait(self.driver, 10).until(exco.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_password")))
        CloupAppSpider.driver.find_element_by_id("id_name").send_keys(pword)
        CloupAppSpider.driver.find_element_by_id("id_password").send_keys(uname)
        CloupAppSpider.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary").click()
        Webwait(self.driver, 10).until(exco.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "col-lg-8")))
        html = CloupAppSpider.driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
        bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        text = bs_obj.find("div", {"class": "col-lg-8"}).find("p")
        obj = text.get_text()
        obj = obj + str(random.randint(0, 100))
        self.driver.close()
        yield{
            'text': obj
        }
```