# Lost UI Shared Context Error - Running protractor tests in headless chrome

Tags: angularjs, angular, selenium, google-chrome, protractor

I am attempting to run protractor tests locally using chrome but in headless mode, I have seen the [docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#using-headless-chrome) and added the appropriate options to my config file:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [ '--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=800,600' ]
    }
  }
```

Upon running, I encounter the following error:

```
[1009/122000.081:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.
```

I tried removing the `--disable-gpu` flag as I read this may not be needed in future version of Chrome. I currently have latest Chrome installed (69.0.3497.100) and am using windows 7.

What do I need to do in order to get the tests running in headless mode? My intention is to check I can run in headless mode fine locally and then I want to get it running also in Chrome headless mode on a linux Jenkins node, where we are currently using XVFB but its proving to be too flaky with timeouts in tests for example.

Thanks

**EDIT**

With regards to others marking this as a duplicate - I should have said that my tests fail to run when I attempt to use the headless option, without the chrome options set, Chrome launches as expected and the test run and pass successfully.

My tests fail with no such element found type errors and if I view the screenshots taken on the failures, I just see a white square inside a black background (probably as per the --window-size option I was setting)

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143413/errorgpu-process-transport-factory-cc1007-lost-ui-shared-context-while-ini

Comment: I dont this is a duplicate since my tests fail only when running under headless mode @Infern0

Comment: @DebanjanB this is not a duplicate, see my Edit please

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned you are using *Chrome headless mode on a linux Jenkins node* you need consider a few factors as follows:

---

### --disable-gpu

When *Headless Chrome* was first released as *GA (General Availability)* by *Google Team* the article [**`Getting Started with Headless Chrome`**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) mentioned that :

```
--disable-gpu \                # Temporarily needed if running on Windows.
```

A note was added as :

> Right now, you'll also want to include the `--disable-gpu` flag if you're running on Windows.

As per the discussion [**`Headless: make --disable-gpu flag unnecessary`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737678) it was clear that :

> The `--disable-gpu` flag is no longer necessary on *Linux* or *Mac OSX*. It will also become unnecessary on Windows as soon as the bug [**`SwiftShader fails an assert on Windows in headless mode`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=729961) is fixed.

You can find a detailed discussion on *What happened under the hood* in the discussion [ChromeDriver showing Lost UI Shared Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094399/chromedriver-showing-lost-ui-shared-context)

So as a first step you need to remove the argument: `'--disable-gpu'`

---

### *flaky tests*

You seem to be executing your tests with the argument `--window-size=800,600` which implies a reduced [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).

In order to utilize the maximum possible *Viewport* you must initialize the *Chrome Browser* in *maximized* mode through the argument: `'start-maximized'`

---

### angular

From [Angular](https://angular.io/) perspective, you can avoid *timeouts* by using the proper `expected_conditions`. You can find a detailed discussion about different expected_conditions in [WebDriverWait not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected)

---

### --headless

Finally, I am not sure what exactly you meant as in *...my tests fail to run when I attempt to use the headless option, without the chrome options set...*. Perhaps the argument **'--headless'** can be invoked only through **`chromeOptions`** and no other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error while running  [1010/161441.019:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.

but my test runs perfect.I have you referred this https://gist.github.com/cvuorinen/543c6f72f8ec917ebfd596802d387aa3

I hope this below may help you

https://cvuorinen.net/2017/05/running-angular-tests-in-headless-chrome/

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome