# How to fix 'Failed to launch GPU process' [.NET CORE / Chromely]

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefglue

I'm trying to setup a new application using `.NET CORE` and `Chromely CefGlue`.

When I build my app, I'm getting a blank page and logging some errors (see bellow)

I'm using Chromely.CefGlue.Winapi nugget package version 68, setting up my application in Window form and built in 64x.

```
var startUrl = "https://google.com";

var config = ChromelyConfiguration
    .Create()
    .WithHostMode(WindowState.Normal)
    .WithHostTitle("chromely")
    .WithAppArgs(args)
    .WithHostSize(1200, 700)
    .WithLogFile("logs\\chromely.cef_new.log")
    .WithStartUrl(startUrl)
    .WithLogSeverity(LogSeverity.Default)
    .UseDefaultLogger("logs\\chromely_new.log")
    .UseDefaultResourceSchemeHandler("local", string.Empty)
    .UseDefaultHttpSchemeHandler("http", "chromely.com") 
    .WithCustomSetting(CefSettingKeys.SingleProcess, true);

using (var window = new CefGlueBrowserWindow(config))
{
    return window.Run(args);
}
```

The chromely.cef_new.log file get this errors messages
`[1226/124833.339:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(119)] Failed to launch GPU process.`

`[1226/124833.344:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1026)] Lost UI shared context.`

And the created window is totaly blank instead of having google page.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tec2Z.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ChromeDriver showing Lost UI Shared Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094399/chromedriver-showing-lost-ui-shared-context)